# DISTINCTCOUNT applying greater than filter (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I am looking to create a measure from a column in a table (to be shown on a card visual) which counts all products where their individual respective counts total is >= 5.

For example:

```
Product Column
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
AAA
AAA
AAA
```

Based on the above the count would be 1 as only AAA has an individual count >=5

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a new table like so:

```
[Product Volume Greater Than 5] :=
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'Table'[Product Column],
        "Count", COUNT ( 'Table'[Product Column] )
    ),
    [Count] >= 5
)
```

And just reference the new 'Product Column' in a visual.

Comment: I made the mistake of adding the code DAX into a new measure at first rather than a new table. This works perfectly, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)